# Cannot add or update a child row with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm making a small program on java which makes updates on an existing database on MySQL. For now, this are the tables that I'm using:

```
create table Empleado (
idEmpleado int(11) not null,
nombre varchar(10) not null,
apellidoP varchar(10) not null,
apellidoM varchar(10) not null,
tipoEmpleado varchar(10) not null,
usuario varchar(15) not null,
contrasena varchar(15) not null,
primary key (idEmpleado))
```

```
create table Horario (
idEmpleado int(11) not null,
entradaL time default null,
salidaL time default null,
entradaM time default null,
salidaM time default null,
entradaMi time default null,
salidaMi time default null,
entradaJ time default null,
salidaJ time default null,
entradaV time default null,
salidaV time default null,
key idEmpleado(idEmpleado),
constraint horario_ibfk_1 foreign key (idEmpleado) references Empleado (idEmpleado));
```

These are my java classes

```
public class Empleado implements Serializable{

private int idEmpleado;
private String nombre;
private String apellidoP;
private String apellidoM;
private String tipoEmpleado;
private String usuario;
private String contrasena;
private Horario horario;

public Empleado (){
}
public Empleado(String nombre,String apellidoP,String apellidoM,String tipoEmpleado,String usuario,String contrasena,Horario horario){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellidoP=apellidoP;
    this.apellidoM=apellidoM;
    this.tipoEmpleado=tipoEmpleado;
    this.usuario=usuario;
    this.contrasena=contrasena;
    this.horario=horario;
}
```

```
public class Horario {
private int idEmpleado;
private Timestamp entradaL;
private Timestamp salidaL;
private Timestamp entradaM;
private Timestamp salidaM;
private Timestamp entradaMi;
private Timestamp salidaMi;
private Timestamp entradaJ;
private Timestamp salidaJ;
private Timestamp entradaV;
private Timestamp salidaV;

public Horario(){
}
```

This is Empleado.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.cafeteria.modelos.Empleado" table="EMPLEADO">
    <id column="idEmpleado" name="idEmpleado">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">horario</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="nombre"/>
    <property name="apellidoP"/>
    <property name="apellidoM"/>
    <property name="tipoEmpleado"/>
    <property name="usuario"/>
    <property name="contrasena"/>
    <one-to-one name="horario" cascade="persist, delete"/>
</class>
```

And Horario.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.cafeteria.modelos.Horario" table="HORARIO">
    <id column="idEmpleado" name="idEmpleado">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
<property name="entradaL"/>
<property name="salidaL"/>
<property name="entradaM"/>
<property name="salidaM"/>
<property name="entradaMi"/>
<property name="salidaMi"/>
<property name="entradaJ"/>
<property name="salidaJ"/>
<property name="entradaV"/>
<property name="salidaV"/>
```

Now, when I run this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nombre="Adolfo";
    String apellidoP="Esparza";
    String apellidoM="Sordo";
    String tipoEmpleado="admin";
    String usuario="adolf";
    String contrasena="queondamiadolf";
    Session sesion;

    Empleado empleado;
    Horario horario;


    horario=new Horario();
    empleado = new Empleado(nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,tipoEmpleado,usuario,contrasena,horario);
    sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    sesion.save(empleado);
    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    sesion.close();
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(empleado.getIdEmpleado()));
}
```

I get this exceptions:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cafeteria`.`horario`, CONSTRAINT `horario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idEmpleado`) REFERENCES `empleado` (`idEmpleado`))
```

Now, I get why this happens. Hibernate is trying to insert a register in table "Horario" first and then in table "Empleado". Because there is no register with the "idEmpleado" that is trying to insert in "horario, in the table "Empleado", i get those Exceptions. My question is: How do I do to make that hibernate insert first in table "Empleado", and then in table "Horario" so this doesn't happens? I want to keep idEmpleado as a pk in "Empleado", and as a fk in "Horario"